# Parse and Convert remote notification NSObject to String

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift3

I am attempting to insert the message passed from a remote notification into an insert statement to a SQLite database inside of my app. I am wanting to do this inside of the didReceiveRemoteNotification function inside of my AppDelegate. The remote notification comes through as NSObject : Anyobject and looks as follows :

```
x = [google.c.a.e: I, aps: { 
alert 
= tyty; 
} , gcm.n.e:
1, google.c.a.c_id: 705599158987573596, google.c.a.udt: e 
id: google.c.a. 
gcm.message_ 
1495589663]; y Y z 
[google.c.a.e: I, aps: { 
alert 
= tyty; 
} , gcm.n.e:
1, google.c.a.c_id: 705599158987573596, google.c.a.udt: e 
id: google.c.a. 
gcm.message_ 
1495589663]
```

[image]

My question is how can I extract the highlighted "alert" portion of the diction and convert it to a string object so that it can be stored in my SQLite database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOT sure X is dictionary or Array , but if dictionary than write like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

            let x = userInfo["x"] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
            let aps = x?["aps"] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
            let alert = aps?["alert"] as? String

            print(alert)
 }
```